# Is it possible to run both PHP and JSP on my droplet

Tags: php, jsp, tomcat, nginx

I would like to use PHP for some webpages and JSP for others. There will be no webpages which use both simultaneously, it's either 100% PHP or 100% JSP for each one. I'm using a LEMP server with Nginx. I've been advised to run Tomcat behind the Nginx server. But I still want Nginx to process all my PHP code. Also, is it possible for both my PHP and JSP webpages to access the same database?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That would work fine.  Your nginx config would configure different servers or locations, one to route to fpm or whatever your php backend is, another for JSP inside tomcat.

Databases are typically language agnostic and multi tenant by design; there's no reason you can't access the same database from any number of apps in any number of languages (Limited, of course, by physical resources).  There may be exceptions, but I can't think of any, and MySQL definitely isn't one.

Whether it's a good idea to have multiple distinct code bases share a database schema is a very different question.  But that's all architecture concerns.  The database certainly doesn't care.